# Android Audio wave sample project

Tags: android, audio, visualization

I am looking for to find out how I can draw an audio wave from an audio file in Android. I have seen it in Telegram and lots of application.when It is playing a recorded wave is draws.I looked for it [here](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) but could not find the right place to figure out how they did that.

Anyway Can you please give me a simple example, or any keywords to search or even a class name which is used in Telegram repository to start from
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Keyword** you are looking for audio wave form in android audio [visualizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html)

**Samples** for audio visualization

- https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer
- https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Audio-Recorder-Visualization-Master

Comment: Thank you so much..Could you please help me find the related classes in Telegram repository?What I search there?